# Redirect stdout to a external program in C/C++

Tags: c, linux

I have a program called **capture** that reads the webcam data and output to the avconv program.

```
./capture | avconv -f mpegts udp://10.1.62.252:5050
```

Now I have to output to avconv inside my C program.

So, instead of output to the stoud:

```
fwrite(p, size, 1, stdout);
```

I need to do do something like that:

```
system("stdout | avconv -f mpegts udp://10.1.62.252:5050");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to learn about the [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output generated by `avconv`?

Comment: avconv encapsulate to h264. Best regards. There are missing flags that i removed to simplify.

Comment: Note that you're not actually asking out redirecting your `stdout`. Rather, you're asking how to redirect the `stdin` of an external program. To that question, there are already answers: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187734), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116) (stdout, but answers apply)

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/); it has *several chapters* to answer your questions

Comment: What I meant was if `avconv` sends any output to its `stdout` or `stderr`, what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [popen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) for this purpose.

```
FILE *f = popen("avconv -f mpegts udp://10.1.62.252:5050","w");
```

then use [fwrite()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) to write.

**PS:** Actually, this method is not redirecting `stdout` of your c program but it is using `pipe stream` concept to provide input to `avconv` from your code.

Comment: Since this is linux, and the data is binary, this works out fine. But in the general case, `popen` does not support a binary mode. Also, note that you use `pclose` to close the file, not `fclose`.